# How to calculate group and outcome numbers using known values

Tags: r, statistics, metafor

When trying to perform a meta-analysis using the *metabin* library, I need the values below:

1. event.e,
2. n.e,
3. event.c, and
4. n.c

However, I don't have these values, so was hoping to calculate them using known data: Odds Ratio + logOR, 95% CIs (Upper and Lower), Total number with/out disease (i.e. sums of the columns in the 2x2 vector I want to determine), Standard Error and Sample Variance.

I was hoping the 'escalc' function would assist, however there doesn't seem to be a parameter for what I need. i.e. have tried:
`escalc(measure="PR", x1i=diseasePOS, x2i=diseaseNEG, ni=(diseasePOS+diseaseNEG), yi=logOR , vi=sampVar, sei=stdEr, data=so.data)`

Current table as per below:

```
OR <- c(1.8,1.41,1.07,1.906)
l95ci <- c(0.9,1.1,0.415,0.623)
u95ci <- c(3.3,1.8,2.811,6.285)
diseasePOS <- c(76,72,64,54)
diseaseNEG <- c(10502,7941,54,54)
logOR <- c(0.5878,0.3436,0.0677,0.6450)
stdEr <- c(0.3314,0.12563,0.48801,0.58963)
sampVar <- c(0.1099,0.0158,0.2382,0.3477)

so.data <- data.frame(OR,l95ci, u95ci, diseasePOS, diseaseNEG, logOR, stdEr, sampVar  )
so.data
```

Therefore hoping to get the XXXX values to fill this grid:

```
        |  diseasePOS   diseaseNEG
--------+-------------------------
Treated |  XXXX         XXXX
Control |  XXXX         XXXX
TOTAL   |  [diseasePOS] [diseaseNEG]
```

(Which would be ai, bi, ci, di in escalc).

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to conduct a meta-analysis on the effect estimates directly?

Comment: Was hoping to created a Forest plot (hence was planning on using output from metabin beforehand). Would I be right in thinking I just need to calculate 'effect size' to build my Forest plot?

Comment: for a forest plot you need the estimates and CIs from the orginal study, and the pooled estimate and CI however you decide to calculate it.  you don't need to go back to the original data, in fact its not often appropriate if there were eg adjustments for covariates in the analysis.  i don't know metabin.